# How do I replace commas with dot in the quoted sub-string only?

Tags: php, regex, string, codeigniter

Suppose I have a string:

```
$string =  'apple, cat, dog, "0,445",symphony, "0,454"';
```

What output I want is:

```
$string =  'apple, cat, dog, "0.445",symphony, "0.454"';
```

Comment: you should provide the source of your string, because this looks like a generated output ;)

Comment: Yes, it is a generated string from an API.

Comment: its fine - but `apple` and `0,445` must have a different field isn't it ? it would be helpful if you can provide an example of your json here ...

Comment: I'm sorry sir, the json contains confidential data which can not be shared publicly. But the format is same as above even the position is same as above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using `preg_replace`

```
$string = preg_replace('/("\d+),(\d+")/','$1.$2',$string);
```

Comment: What if there is no numbers in double quotes?

Comment: I think the commas here is for thousands separator.

Answer (score 1):

Please find work around for your requirement,

```
$string = 'apple, cat, dog, "0.445",symphony, "0,454"';
$array = str_replace('*comma*', ',', explode(',',preg_replace_callback('|"[^"]+"|', function ($matches) {return str_replace(',', '*comma*', $matches[0]);}, $string)));
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
}
$string = implode(",", $array);
```

I took the reference of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16483399/6556397).   Here is your working [code](https://eval.in/1054236).

Comment: create_function?

Comment: Either I callback outside function or create anonymous function to perform the required operation. So I created anonymous function without name by using create_function()

Comment: create_function() is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression : https://regexr.com/3uvj0

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\".)(,)(.*\")/', '$1.$3', $string);
```